# If RadioButton.Checked

Tags: directory, radio-button, load

I need help loading text file in TextBox3.Text with 3 possible options.
1. If there is nothing in TextBox.Text
2. If there is some help text explication to say user what he have to load
3. if correct path then..

I have all good if I choose only from pathn but I need the 3 option.
My code:

```
 If (TextBox3.Text = "Enter the path from your computer to your text file") And (TextBox3.Text = "") And RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
            Dim FILE_NAME = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "\default.txt")
        End If

        If TextBox3.Text <> "" Then
            FILE_NAME = TextBox3.Text
        End if
```

PS: Dim file_name is already declared, but i didnt want to enter here all that codes. Also I tried to not add () and laso looked in MSDN declaration and did exactly same but it wont load nothing, if I dont enter path, OR if I let the explication to user so it wont load default.txt

Thank you

Comment: so everywhere where is = I will replace with == ? Did I understand correct?

Comment: it doesnt work it underline blue and say "Expression extended" so the code will get error. :(

Comment: I tried to add you: If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox3.Text) And RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
                Dim FILE_NAME = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "\default.txt")
            End If  BUT it is same not loaded directory txt file in TextBox :(

Comment: Is that not because your path.combine doesn't return a string, it's returning a path?

Comment: its returning a path yes default.txt in app directory

Comment: I think your looking for an OR statement (TextBox3.Text cannot be both "Enter the path..." AND "") there's something wrong with your logic there

Comment: I know that OR statement is logic but in my case nothign seems to get work and load that path in TextBox:(

Comment: that *because* you're seeing if textbox3 is both `TextBox3.Text = "Enter the path from your computer to your text file") And (TextBox3.Text = "")` - so it will never be true!!

Comment: never be true? it is actually true as it is property of textbox field, so ti is still there to indicate what user must do, the text is in field by default. I think you didnt undertand and you know even less then I do. bye

Comment: How can it be both a value AND empty? That's what your if statement is saying!! So your IF statement will always be false!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to explain to you what I have been (trying) to explain in the comments (obvoiusly) without much success:

You have written, as your first line:

```
If (TextBox3.Text = "Enter the path from your computer to your text file") And (TextBox3.Text = "") And RadioButton1.Checked = True
```

## So, YOU are testing (in a shorter way):

```
IS(TextBox got the value of "Enter the path from your computer to your text file")?


Yes?
   Then IS (textBox ALSO the value of "")


 Yes?
   Then IS (the radio button also checked?)
```

However, you're code will NEVER REACH the 'is the radiobutton...' part, Since textbox cannot be both

```
"Enter the path from your computer to your text file" AND "" (nothing/Blank)
```

I hope you now understand the reason for your code never executing that part of your first if statement.

It's impossible for the code to be true with that condition, and I hope now you will be able to see why.

Comment: So how do i code it? I need 2 option thats why i have 2 radiobuttons, only 1 can be applied thats why i dotn use checkboxes. next the field contains some text like aka mousehove but it is inside the property, and dont tell me this never work as i run one microsoft software and it has same options. i will hire some guru idk to pay lil bit for this, but DO NOT say its not possible as it is as i saw it not one time.